# Using two meteor project with docker - ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8082

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, meteor

I know it sounds silly but I have to create two meteor project, one as a "server" on port 8081 and another one as a "client" on port 8080 and run both with docker.
The client must not create a mongodb instance as it should connect to the server's one.
I know that the server will create the mongodb on port 8082 automatically.

Using `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:8082/meteor` works fine when launching everything separately. But when using Docker, it tells me that client can't connect to the mongo on port 8082.

What I want is to be able to connect the client to the mongo on 8082 or to connect both the client and the server on a full mongodb on port 27017.

Here are the files:

Server's DockerFile:

```
FROM node:10

ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
ENV ROOT_URL="http://localhost:8081"

RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/" | sh

COPY . /usr/src/server

WORKDIR /usr/src/server

#RUN chmod -R 700 /usr/src/app/.meteor/local

RUN meteor npm install

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

client's DockerFile:

```
FROM node:10

ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
ENV ROOT_URL="http://localhost:8080"

RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/" | sh

COPY . /usr/src/client

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

#RUN chmod -R 700 /usr/src/app/.meteor/local

RUN meteor npm install

RUN export MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:8082/meteor

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  server:
    build: ./Server
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: "meteor run -p 8081"
    links:
      - database
  client:
    build: ./Client
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    command: "meteor run -p 8080"
    environment:
      -  MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:8082/meteor
    depends_on:
      - server
  database:
    image: mongo:3.6.4
```

Here is the error I get :

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:8082] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8082]
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.496(0)? (STDERR)     at Pool.<anonymous> (/root/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.3.1.1.v3rpzk.m5kk8++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.499(0)? (STDERR)     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.501(0)? (STDERR)     at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.502(0)? (STDERR)     at Connection.<anonymous> (/root/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.3.1.1.v3rpzk.m5kk8++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.503(0)? (STDERR)     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.504(0)? (STDERR)     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.505(0)? (STDERR)     at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.506(0)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.3.1.1.v3rpzk.m5kk8++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.507(0)? (STDERR)     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.508(0)? (STDERR)     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.509(0)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.509(0)? (STDERR)     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.511(0)? (STDERR)     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
client_1_a42af00d59c0 | W20190311-15:01:13.511(0)? (STDERR)     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Alright, thanks for the help but I've managed to do it. Here are the files :

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  client:
    build: ./Client
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    command: "meteor run -p 8081"
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://database:27017/meteor
  server:
    build: ./Server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: "meteor run -p 8080"
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://database:27017/meteor
  mobile:
    build: ./application
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - server
      - database
  api:
    build: ./Client/api
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    command: node apiLinks.js 4000 database
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    image: mongo:3.6.4
```

Client/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
ENV ROOT_URL="http://localhost:8081"

RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/" | sh

COPY . /usr/src/client

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

#RUN chmod -R 700 /usr/src/app/.meteor/local

RUN meteor npm install

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Server/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
ENV ROOT_URL="http://localhost:8080"

RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/" | sh

COPY . /usr/src/server

WORKDIR /usr/src/server

#RUN chmod -R 700 /usr/src/app/.meteor/local

RUN meteor npm install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And in the code I've replaced all the url. For example, instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8080` I have now `http://server:8080`.

You might notice that server is now on port 8080 and client on port 8081. I had to switch them, that was part of the subject which changed later.

Comment: Did you try to change mongo url to something like this `mongodb://database:27017/meteor` ?

Comment: It wouldn’t work cause the port 8081 corresponds to the meteor Server and not a mongodb.

Comment: You are not pointing to `localhost` but to `database` address  which can have started mongo on same port. But i think that default mongo port is 27017? So your full address should be `mongodb://database:27017/meteor`.

Comment: The problem when doing that is that the client will be directly connected to the database. Instead, it should be connected to the server which is connected to the database.

Comment: So you `server` meteor exposed somehow mongo on port `8082`?  Then it should be available for `client` at address `mongodb://server:8082/meteor`

Comment: Yes exactly, it should, but even with this configuration, it still makes the same error (ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.3:8082)

Comment: I don't see that in your `server` configuration. How do you exposing this mongo db through meteor? Also you stated that when run manually everything work. What are your steps when you start them manually, I mean what command do you use?

Comment: It's because Meteor launch it by itself when you run the project, on the meteor app port + 1 (8082 here).
Manually, I start my mongodb, then I start my server ```meteor run -p 8081``` and finally,```export MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:8082/meteor``` and  my client ```meteor run -p 8080```.

Comment: I'm not an expert of meteor, so maybe you just need to add `EXPOSE 8082` to you `server` Dockerfile. And then try to connect with `mongodb://server:8082/meteor` in you client meteor

Comment: Doing that would bind my Server app on port 8082. And my Server app have to be on port 8081. I just need to be able to connect to the miniMongo created by the Server app on port 8082.

Comment: But I mean you should add additional `EXPOSE 8082` and leave everything else like it is now

Comment: Where should I add this ```EXPOSE 8082``` ?

Comment: In you `server` Dockerfile it can be after `EXPOSE 8081`

Comment: I'll try that this week-end. I'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

A Meteor app does not expose mongodb directly. It's only in development that it starts one for you.

If you want to connect one meteor app to another, you should use `DDP.connect` with the server's url.

You can then subscribe to data from that server and call meteor methods on that server.

Comment: That's what I did first, but my Client tried to connect to the miniMongo on port 8081, which is a meteor app, not a mongoDB.